# use regular expression to find an url in python

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to parse all titles from the website and create a new variable for user input for keywords of the title, then return the matched title and related url, can anyone help to see why I can't get the url, it returned an empty list instead, thanks you

```
import re, urllib.request
link = "http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~dpierz/news.html"
web_page = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
lines = web_page.read().decode(errors = "replace")
web_page.close()
titles = re.findall('(?<=<span itemprop="headline">).+?(?=</span>)', lines, re.DOTALL)
for name in titles:
    print(name)
user = input("Please enter a word to searh for: ")
for title in titles:
    if user in title:
        print(title)
        print(re.findall('(?<=<a itemprop="url" href=").+?(?="><span itemprop="headline">"{}"</span>)'.format(title), lines, re.DOTALL))
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to paste the import re, urllib.request

Comment: DON'T. Use `BeautifulSoup` to extract links and their URLs.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r'<a itemprop="url" href=(".*?")><span itemprop="headline">{}'.format(title), lines)
```

Comment: I tried it, but there is a bug when case includes "$2.49"